# Laravel: How do I create a custom pivot model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working on a project that has a many to many relationship between `User` and `Club`. This relationship works and I can get the respective objects with: `$user->clubs`. The pivot table I've named `memberships`. I can get the pivot data with `$club->pivot`. Foreign keys are defined for the `memberships` table in migrations.

However, I'd like the pivot table to be represented by a model so that I can easily update attributes of `Membership` such as role (Or even add a `Role` model to `Membership`!) or `status`.

I've looked at "[Defining A Custom Pivot Model](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)" in the docs, but what it says doesn't work for me, I get:

`ErrorException
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct() must be of the type array, object given`

I've also looked at [this description](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2093#issuecomment-28689244) of how to do it, but it's more or less the same as above.

`Membership` model:

```
class Membership extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'memberships';

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}

public function club()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Club');
}
}
```

Has anyone done this before?

Comment: I would recommend to use a proper ORM such as Doctrine2. You won't have errors creating a new Entity because you will control every bit of it instead of being dependent on the Framework itself.

Comment: I quite like the way Eloquent works. I know what I'm trying to do can be done (it's in the docs), just having trouble getting it working.

Comment: Have you tried Doctrine2? It's really nice compared to this. You have your Entity and define EXACTLY what it contains in the code, you make your getters and setters (possible attach some on-save or on-update events) and be done with it. You leave all your configuration of relations in annotations, Doctrine will arrange everything for you. That means you can just create a new Entity without having to worry about how the framework populates it or does what ever with it.

Comment: I've used Doctrine2 with Symfony2 and I like it. However I don't really have the time to be switching the default Laravel ORM.

Comment: When is the exception thrown ?

Comment: This exception is thrown when trying to access the pivot object of either a User or Club

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been solved by a [suggestion by a reddit user](http://www.reddit.com/r/laravel/comments/1vhg0q/custom_pivot_table/cesv15a) to extend `Pivot` in my Membership model. I also had to add `->withPivot('status', 'role')->withTimestamps()` to the relationship declarations in the User and Club models.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding some manual code.

Your Membership model looks ok. You can get all clubs of a $user easily if you define method $user->clubs() where you get all the clubs manually.

```
clubs() {
    $memberships=$this->memberships;
    $clubs=new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection();
    foreach($memberships as $m) {
        $clubs=$clubs->merge($m->clubs);
    }
    return $clubs;
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes I can get all of a User's clubs or a Club's users, but I want to be able to access the pivot table in between by way of a Pivot model.